# Bash prompt takes only the first word of a hostname before the dot

Tags: linux, bash, prompt, hostname

I configured my machine as the following hostname ( in reshat 7.2 )

```
digi.master01.usa.com
```

but my prompt is like this

```
[root@digi ]#
```

while we want

```
[root@digi.master01 ]#
```

any idea how to change it in linux configuration?

Comment: What do you currently have in PS1?  You could use `$(hostname | cut -d . -f 1-2)`

Comment: The default PS1 is ugly in Red Hat-like distros (Fedora, CentOS, etc). Debian/Ubuntu does it *much* better.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In bash you can use two special characters regarding hostname:

- `\h` to get host name up to the first dot
- `\H` to get full host name

If you want anything else you need to make your own version for example with `HOSTNAME` variable:

```
[root@digi ]# HOSTNAME=digi.master01.usa.com   # this should be set automatically by bash

[root@digi ]# PS1="[\u@${HOSTNAME%.*.*} ]#"
[root@digi.master01 ]#
```

Comment: (+1) , on which file I need to edit the - PS1?

Comment: @yael you would need to add this to your `~/.bashrc` file. E.g: add the line `export PS1="[\u@\H ]#"`. Then logout or source the file, `. ~/.bashrc` to make this active.

Comment: @yael Like @datUser said, put this into `~/.bashrc`, eventually `~/.bash_profile` or even `/etc/profile` (system-wide), but for interactive stuff like prompt `~/.bashrc` is the right place.

Comment: last question , I try to create now  digi-master01 insted of digi.master  but without success can you please help me with this ?

Comment: @yael `newhostname=${HOSTNAME/./-}` should do the job or `${HOSTNAME//./-}` to change all dots.

Comment: @jimmij: normally you use `\$` instead of `#` in your prompt, so bash will automatically choose between `$` and `#` depending on UID==0 or not.